# Missing static file django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have working with django CMS and I have this error

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/ 404 (NOT FOUND)`

My setting file is this

```
import os
from base import *
from config import *

gettext = lambda s: s
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))    
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# Application definition
ROOT_URLCONF = 'portal.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portal.wsgi.application'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_HEALTH_URL = ''

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portal', 'static'),
)
```

I create a new extension [like this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/extending_page_title.html#implement-a-basic-extension) this works perfectly, after that I reorder my aplication see image. and now when I use the component save the image but dont showme nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: Use /media instead of /static.

Comment: Hi @Serega Luchko I finally resolve the problem... but in weird way... I have two page extension in my Site I create my extension like the link that I comment in my request.. in my setting.py  in the apps stuff, I change the order this extension and everything work!, any idea..

Comment: May be one extension eclipse another or they are depending.